# inline definition of out-of-class member function in separate file causes linker symbol not found?

Tags: c++, linker-errors

Let's say:

foo.h:

```cpp
struct foo {
    int bar();
};
```

foo.cpp:

```cpp
#include "foo.h"

inline int foo::bar() {return 0;}
```

example.cpp:

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    foo lol;
    std::cout << lol.bar() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `g++ -std=c++20 example.cpp foo.cpp -o example` gives `foo::bar()` symbols not found.

In the book [C++ Primer 5e](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113) at Ch.7.3 p.272 - 273, the authors say that it is possible to declare a class member function first and 'can be made inline later' in the definition. That is:

```cpp
class Screen {
    // ...
    Screen &move(pos r, pos c); // can be made inline later
}
```

```cpp
inline // we can specify inline on the definition
Screen &Screen::move(pos r, pos c) {
    // ...
}
```

Have I put the inline definition in `foo.cpp` in `foo.h` and only compile `example.cpp` the linker of course does not complain. But what is the problem here?

Comment: The inline method should be implemented  in the header file (even if done after the class definition), not cpp (so that the compiler will find it for inlining when compiling other translation units).

Comment: [The definition of an inline function ... must be reachable in the translation unit where it is accessed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)

Comment: See [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370493/inline-function-members-inside-a-class#comment11834330_9370717) : *"You can't put the the inline method in the .cpp file. It still has to go in a header"*

Comment: Is it because the compiler must see the definition of an inline function in each translation unit? If so, i get it;D Thank you guys