# static variables slowing launch time of app

Tags: c++, c, static, constants

I am making a cpp application. I have created a .h file with lots of static variables like

```
namespace MSG {
   static const int MSG_TYPE = 1;
   // many more here like strings, ints, chars.
}
```

This is slowing down the launch time.

I have used these variables in a lot of places.

What can i do to improve the speed while reducing the amount of effort made in changing the code ?

Improving performance is a priority, though.

Comment: use singleton pattern..that should solve the problem.

Comment: i hope there would we other solutions too :)

Comment: Are you sure that those variables slow down startup? How did you check it?

Comment: if the variable is int it can't be the main reason in slowing the application, but if it is a class that has a constructor with a high overload [connecting database or opening disk files...] this may cause slowness, but basic types like int will never slow the start up, in my opinion.

Comment: Make the variables non-static, move the *definitions* to a cpp file, and have `extern` *declarations* in the header.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka we have a another team and they use some profiler. I think that it must be the reason.

Comment: @molbdnilo Would the variables not get initialized before the main function get executed, if i move them to cpp ?

Comment: @AshishNegi Well *if* it does slow your app (and that an if you should verify, how do you know they aren't just lazy? :) see it for yourself ). If those variables are error codes, messages etc you could use `#define` statements (yes not very `c++`ish) but it will solve your problem

Comment: @AshishNegi All "top-level" statics are initialized before `main` is entered.

Comment: @molbdnilo More correctly, all variables at namespace scope will be initialized before `main` is entered, or if they are in a DLL, when the DLL is loaded.

Comment: how many of them do you have to slow it down? 5 billion?

Comment: @JamesKanze so how would moving variables to cpp would better launch time ?

Comment: @AshishNegi There would only be one instance of them in the entire program, and not one instance per translation unit.

Comment: @JamesKanze ok i read a little about translation unit and if it is compile time thing how can it effect launch-time ? should i read more ?

Comment: @AshishNegi Launch time is affected by the number of variables which need initialization.  Having an instance of the variable in every translation unit means more variables than having just one instance for the entire program.

Comment: @JamesKanze do you mean that there are multiple `MSG::MSG_TYPE` at the run time ?

Comment: @AshishNegi There's one per translation unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem (assuming that this really is what is
slowing you down, which would rather surprise me) is that you
have an instance of the variable in each translation unit that
includes the header.  For `int`, this probably isn't an issue,
but if any of the types have constructors, it definitely could
be.  In general, *except* for integral constants, you probably
should not have `static` in a header.  (And be aware that if the
object itself is const, it is static by default.)  Thus, for
a string, it should be:

```
namespace Msg
{
    extern std::string const someMessage;
};
```

and then in a source file:

```
std::string const Msg::someMessage( "whatever" );
```

(The source file should, of course, include the header.)

Note that even with integral constants, you have to be careful;
if the use doesn't result in an immediate lvalue to rvalue
conversion, you will need an actual data declaration.  In every
file that uses it in this way, since there is one instance per
file.

A perhaps better solution here would be to use a class, rather
than a namespace:

```
class Msg
{
public:
    static int const msgType = 1;
    static std::string const someMessage;
    //  ...
};
```

This ensures that there is only one actual instance, but still
allows integral constants to work as integral constant
expressions.  (Here too, you need a single definition in
a source file somewhere.)

Comment: i have `#ifndef` in my file. would that not prevent many instances of the variable

Comment: @AshishNegi If you're talking about an `#ifndef` as an include guard, no.  It will only prevent multiple inclusions of the contents in a single translation unit.

Comment: but would not the final executable have only single variable ?? or am i wrong ?

Comment: @AshishNegi Include guards don't have any effect across translation units.  When you declare something static, you are saying that there is a separate instance for each translation unit.

Comment: I made a simple program from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848189/const-static-variable-defined-in-header-file-has-same-address-in-different-trans with header-guards and now i understand.. thanks.