# static inlined function with static variables

Tags: c++, c++11

After reading [static variables in an inlined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185624/static-variables-in-an-inlined-function), I wrote this test program:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"
#include "f.h"

void g();

int main()
{
    std::cout << "int main()\n";
    f().info();
    g();
}
```

a.h:

```
struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "A::A()\n"; }
    void info() { std::cout << this << '\n'; }
};
```

f.h: (singleton local to each compilation unit because of the unnamed namespace)

```
namespace {
inline A& f()
{
    static A x;
    return x;
}
}
```

g.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"
#include "f.h"

void g()
{
    std::cout << "void g()\n";
    f().info();
}
```

The problem is that I don't get the same results with different compilers:

g++ 4.8.2: OK

```
int main()
A::A()
0x6014e8
void g()
A::A()
0x6014d0
```

clang++ 3.7.0: OK

```
int main()
A::A()
0x6015d1
void g()
A::A()
0x6015c1
```

icpc 15.0.2: no call to A::A() inside g() !

```
int main()
A::A()
0x601624
void g()
0x601620
```

Is this a bug in icpc ? Is the behaviour of the program not defined ? If I replace "namespace {...}" with "static" in f.h, A::A() is called inside g() as expected. Shouldn't the behaviour be the same?

If I remove "namespace {...}" in f.h, A::info() prints the same object address in main() and g(), and A::A() is called only once (with all compilers) as expected.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784892/is-stdcout-guaranteed-to-be-initialized. You cannot really say, that you don't get the constructor call, just that the output doesn't happen. And since you are in static constructor country, you might run into another other bug, instead.

Comment: The program has been compiled with "-std=c++11" with all compilers.

Comment: Your source code and program output don't match up. `main()` outputs `"void g()\n"`.

Comment: @Arne Thanks, corrected

Answer (score 3):

Since C++11 mandates names in unnamed namespaces to have internal linkage, every translation unit should have it's own version of `f()` and, as a result, it's own version of `static A x`. So gcc and clang are correct.

Seems like icpc is not following C++11 standard and instead following C++03, which allowed those names to be declared with external linkage. Since when you explicitly make `f()` internal by using `static` icpc follows the suit, I have a strong suspicion this is simply a bug.

Comment: The program has been compiled with "-std=c++11" with all compilers.

Comment: @Jac That does not protect a compiler from having bugs.

Comment: If it was externally linked wouldn't there be a single object at a single memory location? The icpc run returns two different memory locations. Seems like you are just not getting the output in the constructor call...

Comment: No: there should be (and there is) 1 object per compilation unit (g.cpp and main.cpp) as f() is in unnamed namespace.